# Power BI Paginated Report stopped working

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, powerbi-paginated-reports

This week, a Power BI paginated report that was working, stopped working and is throwing the below error:

There was an error communicating with Analysis Services. Please verify that the data source is available and your credentials are correct. The specified query is too complex to be evaluated as a single statement.

This report is connected to a Power BI dataset, the query was written in DAX and we have used the RSCustomDaxFilter function.

The report was working in our three environments (dev, uat, prod) and has stopped working in all three.

Additional information:

The report and the dataset are in the same workspace.

The reports works without any issue in the Power BI report builder

I have tried to remove all RSCustomDaxFilter, but faced the same error message

The parameters of this filter are also queried from the same dataset, the values of the parameters are loading. The error occurs when running the report (tablix) query

Answer (score 0):

The issue with using RSCustomDaxFilter function is that it currently will not work in daxstudio.